# How can a compile a c codefile as a efi app?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, msbuild, uefi

I have a c code file and I would like to compile it as an efi application.
How can this be done using linux and windows cli tools (i.e. without creating a visual studio project)

Than you

Comment: You cannot just compile existing C code into an EFI application.  You need to modify the code so that it calls the appropriate UEFI protocols, etc.

Comment: [link](https://kagurazakakotori.github.io/ubmp-cn/part1/basics/index.html) Maybe this will help you, but it is Chinese edition.

Comment: Thanks @Li-Guangda,if I understand correctly, this line should suffice ? 'x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -Wall -Wextra -e efi_main -nostdinc -nostdlib \
        -fno-builtin -Wl,--subsystem,10 -o main.efi main.c'

Comment: Yeah. But you need to first install `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` (Linux) before. This is bare metal way to write an efi application without further libraries(`gnu-efi` or `EDK ll`).